# SystemVerilog - Value of member class are not updated

Tags: arrays, pass-by-reference, system-verilog

I have the following base class:

```
class base_transaction extends uvm_sequence_item();

   int rand_int_list [$];   
   bit rand_bit_list [$];


   bit [31:0] data [$];

   //uvm_object_utils\
   `uvm_object_utils(base_transaction)

   //constructor
   function new(string name = "base_transaction");
      super.new(name);
   endfunction: new

   //add to list functions
   function void add_rand_int(ref int  mem);
      $display("array size is %d before push", rand_int_list.size());      
      rand_int_list.push_back(mem);
      $display("array size is %d after push", rand_int_list.size());
      //rand_int_list[rand_int_list.size()] = mem;
   endfunction: add_rand_int

   function void add_rand_bit(ref bit mem);
     // rand_bit_list.
      rand_bit_list[rand_bit_list.size()] = mem;      
   endfunction: add_rand_bit   


   //function my_randomize
   function int my_randomize(int seed);
      int temp, success;
      if (rand_int_list.size > 0)
    begin
       for (int i = 0; i < rand_int_list.size(); i++)
         begin
        // temp = $urandom_range(1,11);
        temp = (($urandom(seed)) + 1);
        rand_int_list[i] = temp - 1;
        success = (temp && success);
         end
       if(success == 0)
         return 0;     
    end
      if (rand_bit_list.size() > 0)
    begin
       for (int i = 0; i < rand_bit_list.size(); i++)
         begin
        // temp = $urandom_range(1,11);
        temp = (($urandom(seed)) + 1);
        rand_bit_list[i] = temp - 1;
        success = (temp && success);
         end
       if(success == 0)
         return 0;
       else
         return 1;
    end
   endfunction: my_randomize

endclass: base_transaction
```

I have the following class which extend the base class:

```
class tx_transaction extends base_transaction;
   bit [15:0]  data_xi;
   bit [15:0]  data_xq;
   int mem_int = 2, mem_int_a = 5;  //TODO- delete

   //uvm_object_utils\
   `uvm_object_utils(tx_transaction)

   //constructor
   function new(string name = "tx_transaction");
      super.new(name);
   endfunction: new


   function void add_rand_macro();
      add_rand_int(mem_int);
      add_rand_int(mem_int_a);
   endfunction: add_rand_macro

   //TODO - DELETE
   function void foo();
      $display("rand mem int: %d %d", mem_int, mem_int_a);
   endfunction: foo

endclass: tx_transaction
```

I call the following function from the sequence (tx_trx - is tx_transaction instance, and i is iterator):

```
     tx_trx.add_rand_macro();
     tx_trx.my_randomize(i+1);
     tx_trx.foo();
```

For some reason the foo function display allwas 2 5 (memt_int, mem_int_a), though those values are updated by the my_randomize function (which random the array which the member class are passed by ref)

Comment: I can not see where you have defined my_randomize_old. Also with the current code, are you getting output on display as 2, 5 or is it 0, 0 as you say? I see that you have initialized mem_int and mem_int_a as 2 and 5. I am wondering why you are getting 0, 0 on the display.

Comment: @Puneet Goel - I updated the question. I got 2 5.

Comment: Alright.. The function add_rand_int rightly passes the value by reference. The issue here is that the inbuilt queue method push_back does not handle parameters by reference or pointers. Actually an int queue (rand_int_list in your case) holds values and not references. And there is no way in SystemVerilog to make a queue hold references (or pointers). So even you you are passing int variables by reference to add_rand_int, the fact that a queue can only hold a value and not a reference messes up with your intention.

Comment: @Puneet Goel -  so do I have another option? I there any stucture which can hold reference?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. In the larger context, what are you trying to achieve? Is your effort in the same direction as your earlier question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888939/system-verilog-implementation-of-randomize ?

Comment: @Puneet Goel -  yes.

Comment: Have you tried using PLI/VPI? Though your mileage will vary based on how much of the SV VPI extensions are implemented by your tool.

Comment: @Puneet Goel -  I don't know  PLI/VPI. Is it something like DPI?

Comment: Somewhat. Look at section 37 of 1800-2012. VPI lets you access the member variables of a class. Search for vpiClassObj in the LRM. I emphasize that your mileage may wary depending on tool implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is that your `rand_int_list` is a queue containing `int` values not reference to int varibles. So though you have passed `mem` as a `ref`, but still it's current value will be stored in the queue, not it's reference.

A workaround to this can be to keep track of location where you have pushed back the value and then use that location to retrieve the randomized values.

Your code may look like this.

```
//add to list functions
function int add_rand_int(ref int  mem);
  $display("array size is %d before push", rand_int_list.size());      
  rand_int_list.push_back(mem);
  $display("array size is %d after push", rand_int_list.size());

  return (rand_int_list.size() - 1);
endfunction: add_rand_int

class tx_transaction extends base_transaction;
   bit [15:0]  data_xi;
   bit [15:0]  data_xq;
   int mem_int = 2, mem_int_a = 5;  //TODO- delete
   int location[string]; // An associative array to hold location of variables in rand_int_list queue

   //uvm_object_utils\
   `uvm_object_utils(tx_transaction)

   //constructor
   function new(string name = "tx_transaction");
      super.new(name);
   endfunction: new


   function void add_rand_macro();
      location["mem_inst"] = add_rand_int(mem_int);
      location["mem_inst_a"] = add_rand_int(mem_int_a);
   endfunction: add_rand_macro

   //TODO - DELETE
   function void foo();
      $display("rand mem int: %d %d", rand_int_list[location["mem_int"]], rand_int_list[location["mem_int_a"]]);
   endfunction: foo

endclass: tx_transaction
```